# Using GROUP BY Inside a CTE for Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using TSQL and AdventureWorks 2014 to try to compute the SUM of all the LineTotals for each unique order, specified by SalesOrderID. I'm joining on the SalesOrderHead.SalesOrderID because in SalesOrderHeader, SalesOrderID is the primary key. This query takes forever to run, and returns duplicates of the SalesOrderIDs, when there sould only be one record returned for each SalesOrderID. Hope that makes sense...

What I'm trying to do is calculate the SUM(LineTotal) grouped by SalesOrderID inside the SumPerOrderCTE, and then join this to SalesOrderHeader to select some additional tables, and only select from SumPerOrder the records who have the SalesOrderID matching SalesOrderHeader.

Any suggestions? I can't seem to figure out why it's not doing what it should..

Here's the output (notice the SalesOrderID's are all the same, and th differences *should* mostly be 0 but are not):
[buggy_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVW6u.png)

Small sample of how the output should generally look:
[desired_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBRwy.png)

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC [dbo].[SalesOrderDataReviewCTE]
AS
WITH SumPerOrder (SalesOrderID, CalculatedSubTotalFromDetail)
AS
(
SELECT
    SalesOrderID
    ,SUM(LineTotal)
FROM AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
GROUP BY SalesOrderID
)
SELECT
    soh.SalesOrderID
    ,soh.SalesOrderNumber
    ,soh.SubTotal AS OriginalSubTotal
    ,spo.CalculatedSubTotalFromDetail
    ,(soh.SubTotal - spo.CalculatedSubTotalFromDetail) AS Difference
FROM AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
    INNER JOIN SumPerOrder spo
        ON soh.SalesOrderID = spo.SalesOrderID
```

Comment: It would help immensely if we had (cut down) tables definitions, sample data and *expected results*. Yes, a narrative can be good but for data related questions, nothing beats being able to actually work with the *data*.

Comment: Even better if you could also prepare a fiddle here for example http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: `SalesOrderID` is PK/FK in those tables, your query should work as-is. After the join you can't have different `CalculatedSubTotalFromDetail` for the same `SalesOrderID`, that's impossible. There must be something else, looks like a Cross Join. How many rows are returned by that Select and how many rows exist in `SalesOrderHeader `

Comment: Why the CTE instead of a `SUM(LineTotal)` in the SELECT clause?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: aggregation *before* join is probably more efficient than *aggregation *after* join.

Comment: @dnoeth most likely the opposite, especially if the join eliminates records. The GROUP BY has to be evaluated first over all data before the results can be joined with the entries in the outer query. `GROUP BY` would have to aggregate everything even if the outer query had a `WHERE` clause that limited rows to a single order.

Comment: Of course, but there's no WHERE-condition in this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems to be working fine:

[image]

Please check for some other issue.

Comment: Hmmm strange... I will look into that. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there was just an issue with how I was executing it, thanks again.

Comment: @leilanihagen: Can you share the issue?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it is, I'm using the DBeaver IDE and I had two versions of my stored procedure in one file. I was highlighting only this one when I executed it, but was getting the weird data and taking forever to execute when I did that. When I commented out the other version, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Why use the CTE?

The CTE is just a handy and one-query way to create a temp table with repeatable code. When you do this, the `SumPerOrder` table is missing all the indexes of `SalesOrderDetail`. Thus, the join with `SalesOrderHeader` takes much longer than what a direct join of `SalesOrderHeader` with `SalesOrderDetail` would do.

The simpler way would be:

```
SELECT
    soh.SalesOrderID
    ,soh.SalesOrderNumber
    ,soh.SubTotal AS OriginalSubTotal
    ,spo.SUM(LineTotal) as CalculatedSubTotalFromDetail
    ,(soh.SubTotal - spo.SUM(LineTotal)) AS Difference
FROM AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
    INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderDetail spo
        ON soh.SalesOrderID = spo.SalesOrderID
GROUP BY spo.SalesOrderID,soh.SalesOrderNumber,soh.SubTotal
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning how everything is executed/scopes and such in SQL. Helps a lot!

Comment: The join doesn't take much longer, because it's a way smaller amount of data to be joined. And you still have to do do the aggregation. Btw, a CTE is exactly the same as a Derived Table, the optimizer doesn't have to materialize it.